# Apply row background based on values in certain column (WPF DataGrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made a tool for database that is showing items with certain filtering options. However after reading some more about WPF and C#. I used this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings tutorial to modify my application to deal with `ItemCollectionViewSource`

I am trying to apply certain background to different rows. I have created Class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Liinos_inspector_FilterTest
{
    class LiinosIDToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                string LiinosID = "";
                if (LiinosID.Trim().StartsWith("7")) return Brushes.Blue;
                if (LiinosID.Trim().StartsWith("6")) return Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            return Brushes.Red;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is XAML part:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="0,146,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF377A6C" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF377A6C" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Arial Nova" Foreground="White" >
        <!--RowBackground="Transparent"-->

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item.YRNRO, Converter={StaticResource LiinosIDToBackgroundConverter}}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Here is XAML for columns:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding YRNRO}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="LIINOS ID" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HAKUNIMI}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="SEARCH NAME" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Currently all rows are red as it looks like this is not true `if (value is string)`. Do anyone have any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you already check in debug mode what is the value pass? Can you share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, or one of them anyhow, is your binding.  When you do:

```
 Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item.YRNRO,
```

It's looking for a property Item on the DataGridRow which has a property YRNRO.

It is more likely you will want to bind to something which is the datacontext of the datagridrow which means you should remove the relativesource binding.

You have a collection of something which is the collectionviewsource. Each row in the datagrid gets a something as datacontext.

Depending on exactly what that is you should use:

```
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding YRNRO, Converter={StaticResource LiinosIDToBackgroundConverter}}" />
```

Or if something has a property called Item which is a complex object with a proprty YNRNO then

```
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Item.YRNRO, Converter={StaticResource LiinosIDToBackgroundConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Second problem was in Converter "value" I had to use `if (value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("7")) return Brushes.Blue;` instead of what was before
`